# How can i export my SQLExpress database from Webmatrix?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server-express, webmatrix

I used webmatrix to write my web app. and now I need to upload my files to a host server via ftp. The database file located in `App_Data` folder it's name: `"db.sdf.backup"`.
The host server uses studio manager to manage the database.

Now, my question is how do i export my database so it would work on their server?

Hey, I have the same problem, I want to export my database from webmatrix to 1and1 servers to publish my web site. Unfortunatly the migrate option of webmatrix is only available for SQL Server database and not for Mysql Database ! Do you have another idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database is in SQL Server Express? The file you mention (`db.sdf`) is a SQL Server Compact database, and WebMatrix indeed uses SQL Server Compact by default. If this is the case you need to convert your database to SQL Server "proper". WebMatrix makes it easier for you by offering the Migrate command in the SQL Server section of the ribbon.